# Finding the color of a pixel in image view error

Tags: java, android, colors, crash, rgb

My program currently displays the image I have taken inside an image view, I have coded a section where when you touch somewhere on the image view it should find the color of said point and display the color by changing the TextView to it. however when I touch the screen the app crashes and closes.
Some of the code do nothing atm such as the SeekBar that is for later on.
Any improvements in my code and how I could improve the way I have completed a task please tell me as I am new to java.

**Activity:**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;


import java.io.File;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int CONTENT_REQUEST = 1337;
    private File output = null;
    Button button;
    ToggleButton Edit;
    Button Finalise;
    ImageView imageView;
    Button ButtonState;
    SeekBar SeekBarState;
    SeekBar seekBar;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    Bitmap bitmap2;
    TextView textView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.CameraButton);
        Edit = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.EditorButton);
        Finalise = (Button) findViewById(R.id.FinaliseButton);
        seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Image_view);
        ButtonState = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.EditorButton);
        ButtonState = (Button) findViewById(R.id.FinaliseButton);
        SeekBarState = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);

        ButtonState.setEnabled(false);
        SeekBarState.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {


                Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                File dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM + "/COMP4"); //Storage/sdcard0/DCIM/COMP4/
                dir.mkdirs();
                output = new File(dir, "COMP4Image.jpeg");
                i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(output));
                startActivityForResult(i, CONTENT_REQUEST);


            }


        });


        Edit.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    SeekBarState = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
                    SeekBarState.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                } else {

                    SeekBarState = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
                    SeekBarState.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                }
            }
        });


    }




    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        ButtonState = (Button) findViewById(R.id.CameraButton);
        ButtonState.setEnabled(false);
        ButtonState = (Button) findViewById(R.id.EditorButton);
        ButtonState.setEnabled(true);
        ButtonState = (Button) findViewById(R.id.FinaliseButton);
        ButtonState.setEnabled(true);

        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(output.getAbsolutePath(), bmOptions);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        final Bitmap bitmap2 = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                int x = (int) event.getX();
                int y = (int) event.getY();
                int pixel = bitmap2.getPixel(x, y);


                int red = Color.red(pixel);
                int blue = Color.blue(pixel);
                int green = Color.green(pixel);
                textView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(red, green, blue));
                return false;


            }
        });


    }


    }
```

**Layout:**

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="Capture Image"
    android:id="@+id/CameraButton"
    android:onClick="buttonOnClick"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginRight="380dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="380dp"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Image_view"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/Image_view" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="1000dp"
    android:layout_height="1000dp"
    android:id="@+id/Image_view"
    android:contentDescription="@string/image_cd_camera"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="Finalise"
    android:id="@+id/FinaliseButton"
    android:onClick="FinaliseOnClick"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginLeft="380dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="380dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<SeekBar
    android:layout_width="500dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/seekBar"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Image_view"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:max="510"
    android:progress="255"/>

<ToggleButton
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="Edit Image"
    android:id="@+id/EditorButton"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/FinaliseButton"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/FinaliseButton"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/FinaliseButton"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="TESTING COLOURS"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:textSize="50dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_above="@id/seekBar"
     />
```

Comment: you need to inspect the logcat and find out the cause of the crash.

Comment: Please post the logcat from when the crash occurs - I'm going to hazard a guess that it's a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/tJ7PQ8a1 @AndyTurner

Comment: http://pastebin.com/tJ7PQ8a1 @muratgu

Comment: @AndyTurner I'm still confused as to where in my program the error is, could anyone help me?

Comment: I've read it and understand why it happens

Comment: Either `bitmap2` or `textView` is null (I'd guess the latter). Which is line 126?

Comment: @Aaron Miller have you find solution for your problem?

Comment: @Stanojkovic Yes however the colour it displays is the wrong colour. I believe it is showing the colour of the coordinates relative to the whole screen rather than the image view. It is another problem I am unsure how to correct.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/UbT48eJ1

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
ToggleButton Edit; --> ToggleButton edit;
Button Finalise; Button ButtonState; --> Button finalise, buttonState;     
SeekBar SeekBarState; --> SeekBar seekBarState;
```

Comment: Are you suggesting this fixes the problem, or just commenting on Java naming conventions?

Comment: Commenting on Java naming convention, code conventions improve the readability of the software, allowing engineers to
understand new code more quickly and thoroughly.

Comment: I agree that conventions are good - but I would explain that you are commenting on convention, and why it is a good idea to follow it, rather than just saying "Use <some code>".

Comment: This improve his coding, too.

Comment: Also, provide a link to a page describing Java naming conventions more comprehensively - variable naming is just one thing.

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf, Java naming convention.